# Command line utility to learn bit twiddling hacks

Tags: command-line, software-rec

I am currently reading Hacker's Delight and would like to practice as I read through the book.

Is there any command line *nix tool to perform binary operations and see output in binary?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a commandline utility, but if you fire up Python in interactive mode you can define integers as bit patterns by preceeding them with `0b` and print them as binary using `bin()`:

```
$ ./python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 17 2014, 08:49:22) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> bin(0b0101 | 0b0111) # or
'0b111'
>>> bin(0b0101 & 0b0111) # and
'0b101'
>>> bin(0b0101 ^ 0b0111) # xor
'0b10'
```

( `#` starts an end-of-line comment ).